# To use a public API to pull JSON data from the site and display it on a page asynchronously

Tags: html, json, xml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Zip Code" id="zipCode">
<button>Get Weather Condition</button>
<table id="description" >
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td id="city"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Temparature:</td>
        <td id="temparature"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Speed:</td>
        <td id="speed"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Humidity:</td>
        <td id="humidity"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Min Temparature:</td>
        <td id="mintemparature"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Max Temparature:</td>
        <td id="maxtemparature"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function convertTemp(val){
        var temp = (((val-273.15)*9)/5)+32;
        return temp;
    }
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(){
    var zipcode = $("#zipCode").val();
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipcode 
            + ",us&appid=b6f0657aa7b18c98e70c7bee5d36f1df",
       dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(result) {
        var response = JSON.parse(result);
        $('#city').text(response.name);
        $('#temparature').text(convertTemp(response.main.temp));
        $('#speed').text(response.wind.speed);
        $('#humidity').text(response.main.humidity);
        $('#mintemparature').text(convertTemp(response.main.temp_min));
        $('#maxtemparature').text(convertTemp(response.main.temp_max));
    });
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I create a weather APL web page, but why it doesn't display any result when I enter the zip code? Please help!

Enter a ZIP Code and use that ZIP to build the URL that will pull the current weather for that area. Then on that same page display the weather. You should display:
The current condition (cloudy, Rain, Partly Cloudy, etc.)
Name of the city
Temperature
Wind Speed and Direction
Humidity
Temp Min and Max
Be sure temps are in US Fahrenheit units.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to fix:

- In your `<script>` tag, you've added an extra `>`. You can change it to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

- When you call your api, use `https` instead of `http`
- You do not need to do `var response = JSON.parse(result);`, since setting `dataType: "json"` already parses it for you. So trying to call `JSON.parse` on an object throws an error. Instead, just use `result.name` etc directly.